# How to Clear LocalStorage before Angular 7App initializes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular7

i am building an JWT login application using Angular 7. i created a service - AccountService, to handle the login / logout functionality, and it works as planned. but my problem is this, the localstorage only clears when an event is fired from the application. and so the tokens and the login variables clears. if a user closes the browser without logging out, and enters the home url in the address bar, it goes to the home page and uses the previous tokens.

how can i ensure that when a user closes the browser or runs the application for the first time, the system clears the local storage completely and prevents access to the home page route  thereby redirecting you to the login route.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Injectable({ 
  providedIn: 'root' application..
})


export class AccountService {

  private baseUrlLogin:string = "/api/account/login";

  private loginStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.checkLoginStatus());    //subject/observable/BehaviorSubject  
  private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem['userName']);
  private userRole = new BehaviorSubject<string>(localStorage.getItem['userrole']);

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient, 
    private router: Router
  ){}

  login(username:string, password:string){

    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrlLogin,{username, password}).pipe(
               map(result => {
                  if(result && result.token){
                      localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', '1'); 
                      localStorage.setItem('jwt', result.token);
                      localStorage.setItem('userName', result.username),
                      localStorage.setItem('expiration', result.expiration),
                      localStorage.setItem('userRole', result.userRole);

                      this.loginStatus.next(true); 
                      this.userName.next(localStorage.getItem('userName'));
                      this.userRole.next(localStorage.getItem('userRole'));
                  }
                  return result;

               })
           );

  }

  logout(){
    this.loginStatus.next(false);
    this.clrLocalStorage();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }


  clrLocalStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', '0');. 
    localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
    localStorage.removeItem('userName'),
    localStorage.removeItem('expiration'),
    localStorage.removeItem('userRole');
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  checkLoginStatus():boolean{
    var loginCookie = localStorage.getItem("loginStatus");         
    if(loginCookie == "1"){ 
      return true;
    }
    this.clrLocalStorage();
    return false;    
  }   

  get isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loginStatus.asObservable(); 
  }

  get currentUserName(){
    return this.userName.asObservable(); 
  }

  get currentUserRole(){
    return this.userRole.asObservable(); 
  }    

}
```

on my home controller, on the ngInit - lifecycle method this is what i have

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let isLoggedIn = this.acc.checkLoginStatus();
    if(!isLoggedIn){
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }else{
      console.log('welcome home... ');
      console.log(localStorage);
    }

  }
```

if i restart the server, i also want it to clear the cache totally, and after launch it all routes  - should redirect to the login page, but i'm in a fix

Comment: in `constructor` of `app.component.ts`... you can clear localStorage

Comment: this is on the component level, i was looking at clearing the localstorage on the app level when the entire application bootstraps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in `main.ts` before Angular gets bootstrapped.

main.ts

```
clrLocalStorage() {
  localStorage.setItem('loginStatus', '0');. 
  localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
  localStorage.removeItem('userName'),
  localStorage.removeItem('expiration'),
  localStorage.removeItem('userRole');
  localStorage.clear();
}
clrLocalStorage();

// Angular bootstrap
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```